# Find steps to solve : $\int_0^t \frac{x \cos u - x^2}{1 - 2x \cos u + x^2} \, du $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int_0^t \frac{x \cos u - x^2}{1 - 2x \cos u + x^2} \, du\quad\text{with}\quad x \in ]-1,1[ $$

> $$ \int_0^t \frac{x \cos u - x^2}{1 - 2x \cos u  + x^2} \, du = \arctan \left( \frac{x \sin t}{1- x \cos t} \right) $$

I have this integral with a known result. The "proof" the book gives is :

> "We recognize that the fraction is $\dfrac{h'(u)}{1+h(u)^2}$ with $h(u) = \dfrac{x \sin u}{1- x \cos u } $"

But it's not that easy to spot, and I would like to know how to find this result without guessing that out of nowhere and without knowing it beforehand.
I've tried substitutions but I can't find a way to make it work.

Any idea on how to solve this ? Thanks !

Comment: The proof is: Differentiate the RHS

Comment: I edited the post to clarify that I want to know how to get the RHS, I would like to get there without knowing what the result is beforehand.

Comment: Since you have put the anti-derivative (answer) up top, people will inevitably be influenced in their method to solve the integral. I suggest putting it within a spoiler or withholding it for the time being. That's just my thought.

Comment: Have you tried using the Weierstrass substitutions?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Shubham.

I tried to use it yes but I didn't know how to solve the expression it leads to...

Comment: @Gaelink [here's what Rubi/Mathematica thinks of it](https://imgur.com/a/BMpGWj9)

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's similar to Wolfram's answer but I'm not familiar with the method that is used and I thought that maybe there was another way, a more "human" way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it gives the expected result, don't forget we're differentiating with respect to u. Then be careful while doing h'(u)/1+h(u)^2.

Comment: Oh, yeah, nvm, misread that.

Comment: It seems like there ought to be a clever geometrical construction that simplifies the integrand right down. The denominator looks like it came from the cosine rule. I've had a go but I can't find the right construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also don't see a way to spot that antiderivative, so here's what I would call the "systematic" way of doing it. That is, simply applying general purpose integration techniques and identities without trying to find antiderivatives by inspection.

When working with integrals involving rational functions of $\sin$ and $\cos$, a standard method of integration is the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) $v = \tan(u/2)$. This means $\sin(u) = 2v/(1+v^2)$, $\cos(u) = (1-v^2)/(1+v^2)$, and $du = 2dv/(1+v^2)$. Applying this to your integrand gives
$$
\int_0^t\frac{x\cos(u) - x^2}{1 - 2x \cos(u) + x^2}du = \int_0^{\tan(t/2)}\frac{x[1-x - (1+x)v^2]}{(1-x)^2 + (1+x)^2 v^2}\frac{2dv}{1+v^2}
$$
We then do a standard partial fraction expansion:
\begin{multline}
\int_0^{\tan(t/2)}\frac{x[1-x - (1+x)v^2]}{(1-x)^2 + (1+x)^2 v^2}\frac{2dv}{1+v^2} = \int_0^{\tan(t/2)}\left[\frac{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}{1 + \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}v\right)^2} - \frac{1}{1+v^2}\right]dv
\\ = \left.\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}v\right) - \tan^{-1}(v)\right]\right|_0^{\tan(t/2)} = \left.\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{2xv}{1 - x + (1+x)v^2}\right]\right|_0^{\tan(t/2)},
\end{multline}
where the last equality comes from the tangent addition identity. The last step is to perform the substitution and use $\tan(t/2) = [1 - \cos(t)]/\sin(t)$ to get
\begin{multline}
\left.\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{2xv}{1 - x + (1+x)v^2}\right]\right|_0^{\tan(t/2)} = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x\sin(t)[1-\cos(t)]}{(1-x)\sin^2(t) +(1+x)[1-\cos(t)]^2}\right)
\\ = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x\sin(t)[1-\cos(t)]}{[1 - x\cos(x)][1-\cos(t)]}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left[\frac{x\sin(t)}{1 - x\cos(t)}\right]
\end{multline}
I've skipped over a fair bit of algebra to give the highlights, but you can check that it all works. So in conclusion,
$$
\int_0^t\frac{x\cos(u) - x^2}{1 - 2x \cos(u) + x^2}du = \tan^{-1}\left[\frac{x\sin(t)}{1 - x\cos(t)}\right],
$$
as desired.

Comment: I thought I got it but after taking a close look I'm not quite sure...
Isn't an x factor missing from your second integral ? If I'm not  wrong, we have on top  :
x*(1-v^2)/(1+v^2) - x^2 
And when you put everythin on the same denominator, on top we end up with :
x(1-v^2) - x^2(1+v^2) = x - x^2 -v^2(x+x^2) = x( 1 - x - v^2(1+x)) 
I don't get why there is no x in yours

Comment: @Gaelink Yes, it appears I forgot to put that in there. The partial fraction expansion and everything after it is still correct.

Comment: (I think you put some x instead of t at the end)
Appart from that, everything seems right ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this helps but ...

\begin{align}\mathcal{I}&=\displaystyle\int \frac{x\cos u-x^2}{(-2x)\cos u+(x^2+1)}\mathrm du\\&=\underbrace{\displaystyle\int \frac{x\cos u}{-2x\cos u+(x^2+1)}\mathrm du}_{\mathcal{I_1}}-x^2\overbrace{\displaystyle\int \frac{\mathrm du}{-2x\cos u+(x^2+1)}}^{\mathcal{I_2}}\end{align}

---

\begin{align}\mathcal{I_2}&=\displaystyle\int \frac{\mathrm du}{-2x\cos u+(x^2+1)}\\&=\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}(-2x)+x^2+1}\left(\frac{2\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}\right)\, \text{ ,via substituting $t=\tan(u/2)$}\\&=2\displaystyle\int \frac{\mathrm dt}{(t(x+1))^2+(x-1)^2}\\&=\frac{2}{x^2-1}\arctan\left(\frac{(x+1)t}{x-1}\right)\, \text{ ,using the formula $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{a^2x^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(ax/b)$}\\&=\frac{2}{x^2-1}\arctan\left(\frac{(x+1)\tan(u/2)}{x-1}\right)\end{align}

---

\begin{align}\mathcal{I_1}&=\displaystyle\int \frac{x\cos u}{-2x\cos u+x^2+1}\, \mathrm du\\&=-x\displaystyle\int\left(\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{x^2+1}{2x(2x\cos u-x^2-1)}\right)\, \mathrm du\\&=\frac{-u}{2}-\frac{x^2+1}{2}\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm du}{2x\cos u-x^2-1}\\&=\frac{-u}{2}+\frac{(x^2+1)}{(x^2-1)}\arctan\left(\frac{(x+1)\tan(u/2)}{x-1}\right)\, \text{ ,using $\mathcal{I_2}$}\end{align}

---

Therefore,
\begin{align}\mathcal{I}&=-\frac{u}{2}+\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\arctan\left(\frac{(x+1)\tan(u/2)}{x-1}\right)-\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1}\arctan\left(\frac{(x+1)\tan(u/2)}{x-1}\right)\\&=\frac{-u}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{(x+1)\tan(u/2)}{x-1}\right)\end{align}

Now, you can put the limits.

**Footnotes**

[Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)